# creating functions and using function calls in PHP

Tags: php

How would one go about creating a function file that is stored outside of the document root? I want to create a function that could accept 2 - 4 arguments and returns the sum of the arguments and want it in an external file.

Comment: I would suggest starting with the [PHP manual](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/) to learn the basics of how to write functions, etc.

Comment: Most PHP files should be outside the document-root by default. Only public files (e.g. bootstrap) should be in the document-root. You can just `include()` or `require()` the file you need. even if it's outside the document root

Comment: php is a server side language, so if you require server side files, you can require them from anywhere on the server, as long as you have permissions to read and access that file.

Comment: @RobertPitt Although it is not recommended, you can also include files which are not on the same server.

Comment: have you ever seen `eval(file_get_contents($external_file))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

file1.php:

```
function funcName($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4)
{
    return $var1 + $var2 + $var3 + $var4;
}
```

file2.php:

```
include("file1.php");

print funcName(5, 15, 20, 10);
```

result of running file2.php:

> 50

Answer (score 0):

Say your document root is `/home/www/site`, you can create a file under `/home/www/lib` and put your functions inside the file. After that you can include the function file from your other files using `include` or `require` directives:

```
include "/home/www/lib/your_func_file.php";
// Then you can call the function that is inside in your_func_file.php
your_func();
```

Read [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) manuel section and examine the examples.